# Equivalent of the `SYM_FUNC_START` macro in linux userspace?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

I am looking for a userspace equivalent to the `SYM_FUNC_START` macro from the linux kernel (`include <linux/linkage.h>`). I want to declare a function in an `.S` assembly file like so:

```
SYM_FUNC_START(assembly_func)
 push %rbx
 mov %rdi, %r8 // %rdi should contain the first argument 
 pob %rbx
 ret 
SYM_FUNC_END(assembly_func)
```

And then be able to define it in a `.h` file like so:

```
void assembly_func(int64_t first_arg);
```

And call it from normal `.c` code. Is this also possible from userspace?

Comment: this has nothing to do with these macros

Comment: Oh, even better! How can I declare a function in a .S file?

Comment: You simply put a label with the function name at the beginning of the code. `function_name:`

Comment: `.globl foo  /  foo: ret` in `foo.S` (replace `/` with a new line) and `void foo(); int main(void) { foo(); return 0; }` in `main.c`. Then `gcc foo.S main.c -o bar`. Double-check that.